# Lock Statement Apparently Not Protecting Critical Code

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Problem: I'm using a C# **lock statement** to protect my variable '_NextId' when I increment it and assign its new value. I don't want any other threads interrupting and snagging the value until the increment has completed.

*Unfortunately*, it doesn't seem to work, because I'm getting duplicates when I run it in a parallel loop. This indicates to me that another thread has managed to sneak into my protected code.

### Here's the code that doesn't work as expected:

```
public class Widget {
    private static int _NextId;
    private object _LockToken = new object();

    public Widget() {
        //I expected this lock to prevent any other thread from assigning its ID until we have
        //completed incrementing the member variable
        lock (_LockToken) {
            ID = ++_NextId;
        }
    }

    public int ID { get; private set; }
}
```

Here's a link to [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bOQH4m) that proves duplicates are created. I interpret that result as indicating the lock doesn't work the way I expected. The DotNet fiddle runs the code above in a parallel loop and then counts how many duplicate IDs were created. If you run it, it will print a message displaying the duplicate count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the `_LockToken` variable as `static` to ensure the locks are taken against the same object.

Comment: Thanks Tarik, that fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, a different `_LockToken` is being created for every widget.

Try adding a `static` modifier to the `_LockToken`, so all instances of the `Widget` class refer to the same "lock token".

Comment: Thanks alxrcs, Tarik was just a bit faster than you answering my question.

Comment: No worries. Glad to see you figured it out. :)